# How can I require two collisions on one of my nodes before removing it from screen?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skphysicsbody, sknode

I have a collision based game with missiles and bombs. Everything works perfect right now with 1 collision and it removes the node from screen.

Although I want to be able to make bomb1 of my "bombs" harder to destroy so I would like to require it being hit twice. How can I do this?

Here are the bombs

```
func enemies() {

    let bomb1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bomb1")
    let bomb2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bomb2")
    let bomb3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bomb3")
    let enemy = [bomb1, bomb2, bomb3]

    // Enemy Physics
    for bomb in enemy {
        bomb1.size = CGSize(width: 55, height: 55)
        bomb2.size = CGSize(width: 55, height: 70)
        bomb3.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        bomb.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bomb.size.width / 4)
        bomb.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemy
        bomb.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.missile | PhysicsCategory.airDefense
        bomb.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.missile | PhysicsCategory.airDefense
        bomb.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false 
        bomb.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        bomb1.name = "enemy1"
        bomb2.name = "enemy2"
        bomb3.name = "enemy3"

    }
```

Here is the function thats called when the bomb hits the missile.

```
 func collisionWithMissile(enemy : SKSpriteNode, missile : SKSpriteNode) {
    enemy.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    missile.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true

    enemy.physicsBody?.mass = 10.0
    missile.physicsBody?.mass = 5.0

    enemy.removeAllActions()
    missile.removeAllActions()

    enemy.removeFromParent()
    missile.removeFromParent()

    enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
    enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    enemy.name = nil

    score++
    scoreLbl.text = "\(score)"

}
```

This may help with the error Im getting

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if contact.bodyA.node != nil && contact.bodyB.node != nil {
        let firstBody = contact.bodyA.node as! Bomb
        let secondBody = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode

        // Bomb1 **********
        if ((firstBody.name == "enemy1") && (secondBody.name == "missile")) {

            collisionWithMissile(firstBody, missile: secondBody)
            atomicExplosion(contact.bodyA.node!.position)
            missileExplosion(contact.bodyB.node!.position)

        }
```

Comment: You can use string interpolation to simplify the `enemies` method. For example, you can create each bomb in the for-loop with `let bomb = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Bomb\(i)")` and assign a name with `bomb.name = "enemy\(i)"`, where `i` (from 1...3) is the loop control variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass SKSpriteNode for your bombs and add a collision counter to this class. Inside your collisionWithMissile func you check the value of this counter and remove the bomb if a given value is reached otherwise you increase the counter.

Your subclass can look like this

```
class Bomb: SKSpriteNode {
  var hitCount: Int

  init(imageNamed: String, hitCount: Int) {
    self.hitCount = hitCount
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageNamed)
    super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size())
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

The init method has hitCount as a parameter, so you can create easily Bombs with different strength. Your collisionWithMissile method could be like this. Just fill the if-else parts with your needed code.

```
func collisionWithMissile(enemy : Bomb, missile : SKSpriteNode) {
  if enemy.hitCount <= 0 {
      enemy.removeFromParent()
  } else {
      enemy.hitCount -= 1
  }
}
```

Comment: if you do not want to subclass, and want an effect that appears damaged, you could use the alpha as a "life counter",  then as more damage happens, the more transparent it becomes

Comment: @Pierre could you give me an example of what this would look like?

Comment: @TimmySorensen have a look at my edited answer. I don't know how your project looks like maybe it could be easier to use another init method for the Bomb class that takes only hitCount as a parameter.

Comment: @Pierre So I would use the subclass Bomb instead of the func enemies like I had at the top? Do i have a subclass for each bomb? I don't have a color to set so I tried just taking that out but got errors so not sure what to do about that. Sorry this is the first time I've used subclass, Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TimmySorensen I changed the init method to make it similar to the one  you used. To your questions: You have only this subclass for your bombs. In your enemies() func you just change the first lines from `let bomb1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bomb1")`to `let bomb1 = Bomb(imageNamed: "Bomb1", hitCount: theHitCountYouWant)`

Comment: @Pierre I seem to be on the right track I am just having some trouble recreating the 4 bombs in the subclass. Am I suppose to have 4 subclasses of the Bomb subclass?

Comment: @TimmySorensen, no you have only this single subclass. Instead of creating your bombs with `SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:)` you use `Bomb(imageNamed:, hitCount:)` for each bomb you create.

Comment: @Pierre Wow i was totally over thinking that! Thanks for your patience! Ok that is working now but when the missile and a bomb contact the app stops. I added the didBeginContact code to the question. let firstBody = contact.bodyA.node as! Bomb is the part that appears to be stopping it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101379/discussion-between-pierre-and-timmy-sorensen).